# Import MySQL MyISAM into SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

*Caveat: I have zero experience with MySQL.*

I've been given a series of files to do a data conversion and would like to migrate the provided data into SQL Server 2008.  The files are:

- *.myd
- *.myi
- *.frm

These file types, as I understand it, are MyISAM.  I believe that if I had a running MySQL instance, migrating to SQL Server would be fairly straightforward.  I could could either use SQL Server's import wizard or [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL v1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=69739c8c-ac82-41de-b9e6-8fa5ae2594d9&displaylang=en).  Unfortunately, these files are what I'm stuck with -- I just don't have access to the original MySQL instance.

I also don't presently have MySQL as a running instance locally and I'm not sure if there would be compatibility issues with the files I have.

Can I attach them to MySQL 5.5 with the goal of performing a SQLDump or perhaps to use either tool mentioned above?  Am I missing a better way?

Comment: You should be able to drop those into a functioning MySQL install, then use the migration assistant and/or just use mysqldump to get the raw SQL necessary to rebuild the database. But I doubt Microsoft would write a parser for the binary mysql files, just for import purposes.

Comment: @Marc B - is dropping them into a functioning MySQL install trivial?

Comment: Put the files into MySQL's data directories, restart the server, and unless your version is drastically different than the one they were created on, they should be indistinguishable from a "real" database.

Comment: It was indeed that easy.  I had to find the My.ini to determine the data directory, then restart MySQL service.  Voted up your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily attach them to MySQL 5.5. Then you can dump the tables using mysqldump (be aware that you will need to either modify dump and remove mysql-specific stuff from the dump, or probably customize mysqldump output - check mysqldump documentation for details). You can also try to link Mysql instance to SQL Server, and then copy tables using `SELECT ... INTO [sql_server_table_name] FROM [mysql_table_name]`. 
In any case, the hardest part is to migrate stored procedures/triggers. Mysql and SQL Server have quite a different syntax for them, so you probably cannot automate this process.
**Update**
Also, I forgot to mention that you will have to modify mysql `auto_increment` columns to `IDENTITY([next_auto_increment_value],1)` SQL server.